# Compiling Project with command line but Debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, command-line, compilation, maven-plugin

I have a big project which I can compile and run with Maven in command line.

I want to import it into eclipse to dive into the code and understand it better, but there are lots of not supported pluggins.

[image]

Is there a way to import the whole project, including target folders and compiled classes via command line but debugging it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using m2e. Those unresolved plugins should not really matter. If you do a Maven build from inside Eclipse, Maven will download all those needed plugins during the process and then the errors shown in the POM files will just vanish, as m2e now recognizes the newly available plugins.